# PM2 Production Optimization

Tags: node.js, optimization, production, pm2

I just tried deploying node app on a "production" environment.

I use PM2 for running the app by using this command. `pm2 start app.js --name <appname>`

My questions are:

1. Why I can't see the `console.log` of the `child_process` I forked?
2. Is it okay to call many `child_process.fork`?

---

**EDIT 1**

Basically, what the app do is watching a folder using `chokidar`.
When there's a new file, it will check the file type, then it will do one of the following items:

1. If the file type is `.FLV` the app will add a document to a MongoDB collection hosted in mLab.
2. If the file type is `.PNG` the app will upload the file to S3 bucket using `child_process.fork`.
3. If the file type is `.MP4` the app will upload the file to S3 bucket using `child_process.fork`, then run and `FFmpeg` command to generate a screenshot that runs on another `child_process.fork` which then trigger process number `2` above, it also does a MongoDB update on another `child_process.fork`.

This is the code snippets

**1. Chokidar Watcher (app.js)**

[image: Chokidar Watcher]

---

**EDIT 2**

Added code snippets for how I use chokidar and forking a child process.

Comment: You need to ask one question, not two. Also, show your pm2 config for the app and any relevant app code as well.

Comment: @Paul Hi Paul, thanks for the comment. This is my first time deploying to a production environment, that's why I got a load of questions. Sorry if the post become too broad, I just edited it so it become more focused

Comment: And the pm2 config?

Comment: @Paul I don't add any PM2 config, just plain command to start it
`pm2 start app.js`. Oh and exporting some ENV before this command. Do I need specific config for PM2 to run better in production?

Comment: There are a lot of pm2 options, they depend on your environment as to which run best.  For what  you showed so far you're probably fine.

Comment: @Paul I see, okay I will read on more about PM2 options. Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the children's stdout and stderr to use the parent's pipe, you need to tell it to do so as part of the spawn command.  This is explained in the docs:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdio

It's fine to spawn other processes as needed, subject to whatever system  limits you have, though code sample seems to just spawn one at a time.